# converting xsl-fo to (x)html?

Tags: php, html, xslt, porting, xsl-fo

Is it possible to transform XSL-FO into XHTML? I have tried RenderX style sheet **fo2html.xsl** but the output is completely broken.

What I am trying to achieve is to let the user edit the XSL-FO content in a Flash app (AS2); so I'd like to convert it to HTML, let the user edit it, and then convert back to XSL-FO (and eventually to PDF at the end).

**EDIT : actually running php 5.3.5 w/ apache 2.2**

Actually that's what I do :

```
$in = '.\\files\\in.fo';
$out = '.\\files\\out.fo';

// transform
$xp = new XSLTProcessor();
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML(file_get_contents($in));
$style = new DOMDocument();
$style->load('D:\\apache\\htdocs\\mv\\last\\myvisit\\outils\\xslt\\stylesheets\\fo2html\\fo2html.xsl');
$xp->importStylesheet($style);
// XML > HTML
$html = $xp->transformToXML($xml);
echo $html;
```

where $in looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master margin-bottom="35.4pt" margin-left="70.85pt" margin-right="70.85pt" margin-top="35.4pt" master-name="pm0" page-height="841.9pt" page-width="595.3pt">
            <fo:region-body margin-bottom="35.45pt" margin-top="35.45pt" overflow="visible" region-name="body"/>
            <fo:region-before extent="771.1pt" overflow="visible" region-name="header"/>
            <fo:region-after display-align="after" extent="771.1pt" overflow="visible" region-name="footer"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pm0" orphans="2" white-space-collapse="false" widows="2">
        <fo:flow flow-name="body">
            <fo:block end-indent="0pt" line-height="13.7pt" start-indent="0pt" text-align="start" text-indent="0pt">
                <fo:inline font-family="Times Roman, serif" font-size="12pt">%%patient.identite%%</fo:inline>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block line-height="13.7pt">
                <fo:leader line-height="13.7pt"/>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block end-indent="0pt" line-height="13.7pt" start-indent="0pt" text-align="start" text-indent="0pt">
                <fo:inline font-family="Times Roman, serif" font-size="12pt">%%listePrescriptions[withCompoDecomposee,withLastAdmin]%%</fo:inline>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

and output HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>XSL FO Document</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css"/>
        <style type="text/css">
        <![CDATA[
            a { color: black; border: none; text-decoration: none; }
            img { border: none; } 
        ]]>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white" marginwidth="6" marginheight="6" leftmargin="6" topmargin="6">
        <div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is "completely broken" with the output of the renderX stylesheets? I have used them before and they worked very well.

Comment: can you post the Html output that you had please ?

Comment: I think it will be very hard doing it from scratch. Perhaps your question should show a bit of XSLT, otherwise which kind of answer are you expecting?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, xsl-fo is actually used for *just* pdf display. Have you tried something different such as xml>xhtml or xml>xsl-fo with a xslt transformation? That way, you'll have both on a single touch :)

Comment: The correct in the workflow is to use HTML as source (!), see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21345708/287948

Answer (score 0):

XSL-FO is XML, so use the following:

- [loadVariables](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/00000575.html) to call the PHP script in Flash
- [textArea](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/00002895.html) to edit the XSL-FO in Flash
- [sendAndLoad](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/00001174.html) to send the edited document back to the server for PDF conversion